# Could not write message to OutputStream: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Connection timed out

Tags: web-services, jboss5.x

I am getting this error when we move our database to new server. The application at the new server and the database at older server runs fine. But when we move the database to new server the server log shows this error.
Below is the server log. We are using jboss-5.1.0.GA.

2013-02-22 01:02:31,336 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/]] (main) StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageException: Could not write message to OutputStream: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Connection timed out: connect; nested exception is javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Connection timed out: connect
at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessage.writeTo(SaajSoapMessage.java:169)